# Why can't I see any other simulators in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to learn swift using[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7t2h.png) Xcode but am unable to see any other simulators.
I tried a few things like making a new scheme but it still doesn't work. Any idea what can be done?

Comment: I guess it's an iOS app. Did you download the other simulators, with an iOS version compatible with your target? Ie, iif you have only iOS14 simulators, but your app is for iOS15+, they won't show...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have configured this project as a Mac app. Therefore there are no "simulators", as there is nothing to simulate; the app runs directly on your Mac.

If you *intended* to configure this project as an iOS app, the best course is to throw this project away and start over, and this time, when you make a new project, be more careful about specifying what kind of project it is to be.

[image]